# Set_value fallback in code igniter to obtain integer from URL address

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, codeigniter

I'm using the codeigniter framework in order to update records from a database, where the user first selects the ID of the item from a drop down list on the form

This ID gets added onto the URL where all of the relevant information for that item is obtained from the database.

I used a small bit of javascript in order to achieve the ID being added onto the URL.

My problem is that even though I have the set_value() field on the form to the ItemID, it still doesn't retrain the ID within the drop down box after the page reloads?

I need the ID to stay inside of the drop down list, as well as being on the URL at the top of the page

here is my code for the form

```
<?php echo form_dropdown('ItemID', $ItemIDListFromDatabase, 
                                set_value('ItemID', 1), 'id="ItemID"'); ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
            $( '#ItemID' ).on( 'change', function( e ){
                document.location.href = "<?php echo site_url('site/Myform) ?>" + "/" + $( this ).val();
            });
        </script>
```

As you can see above I've tried adding a random fallback number to this set_value call, which works but only to update the item with ID of 1, I need it to be able to update the Item corresponding to the ID on the URL

I hope this makes sense, all help appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by very simply using

```
$this->uri->segment()
```

Without knowing your full URL address, I don't know the exact number to put into the segment, but going by your code supplied just change the following to this:

```
<?php echo form_dropdown('ItemID', $ItemIDListFromDatabase, 
                                set_value('ItemID', $this->uri->segment(3)), 'id="ItemID"'); ?>
```

This will obtain the value within segment 3 of your URL.

A quick tip if you can't figure out what the correct URI segment should be, you can test it out by echoing different values until you find the correct one

E.g.

```
<?php echo $this->uri->segment(3); ?>
```

This will display what ever is displayed on your third segment of the URL

Comment: I shall give this a go now